# Why won't my ASP.NET application export CSV when hosted as an Azure Web app?

Tags: azure, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-5

MY application exports CSV's fine when I test it from Visual Studio, but when I deploy it to an Azure as a Web app, instead of exporting a CSV I get a Error code: ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE.

Below is the method I use :

```
public void ExportEmpReport(int? er_id)
    {
        var er_hdr = db.expense_report_hdr.Include(w => w.employeeExpUser).Where(x => x.ID == er_id).FirstOrDefault();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        sw.WriteLine("Employee Name: " + er_hdr.employeeExpUser.fullname + ", Period: " + er_hdr.period + ", Expense Report ID: " + er_id);
        sw.WriteLine("Date of Expense , Expense Class , Detail , Cust/Conv , Notes , Amount , GL Code , Project Code");

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExpenseReport_" + er_id + ".csv");
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

        var lines = db.expense_report_line.Where(y => y.er_id == er_id);

        foreach (var line in lines) 
        {
            string exp_class = line.expenseType.expense.ToString().Replace(",", "");
            string detail = (line.expense_detail != null) ? line.expense_detail.Replace(",", "") : "";
            string cust_conv = (line.cust_conv != null) ? line.cust_conv.Replace(",", "") : "";
            string notes = (line.notes != null) ? line.notes.Replace(",", "") : "";
            sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7}", line.expense_date, exp_class, detail, cust_conv, notes, line.amount, line.gl_code.GL_code, line.project_code));
        }

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();                       
    }
```

Comment: What's the stack trace? What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: I don't get any stack errors when running it in Visual Studio. The only error I get is when it is hosted in Azure. I'm not sure how to debug it once it's hosted. I just get a "might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address." error. But the method is there so I don't know why it says it isn't. The app works perfect when hosted on my local server but not as an Azure web app.

Comment: You'll want to look that up, then come back here and ask any questions you still have. We can't debug your app for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions you may use to try and troubleshoot it:

**A. Debug the web app locally, while connected to the DB on Azure. Are the tables being read correctly?**

If the code fails to read the data from the database, make sure that the database is updated to the latest schema.

**B. If it reads the data correctly, debug it step by step, and watch exactly where it fails.**

If it fails at a particular line, remove/replace some lines of code until the local web app is running correctly against the DB on Azure. You may be able to identify the offending line(s) of code, and then report back here to allow others to help you troubleshoot further.

**C. Once you get it working with the local app against the DB on Azure, deploy the updated project code to the Web App on Azure to see if it still runs correctly.**

If it still doesn't work, maybe there's a setting on your Web App that is preventing it from running the code successfully.

**D. Check the version of the .NET Framework on the Web App in Azure. The choices should be v3.5 or v4.6 (for non-Core 1.0 applications).**

If it has the wrong version selected, make sure you select the correct version.

**E. Enable Remote Debugging of the Web App running on Azure.**

There's a Remote Debugging feature that you can toggle on/off in the Application Settings blade, where you can also select the VS version (2012, 2013, 2015). Turn it on to pinpoint which line of code it's failing at.

Comment: Great job in giving me my options. I found the bug at step B with a column being a different format in the azure DB than the local DB. I will definitely be referring to your list in the future.